# org-mode: framebreak does not work with label option in exported beamer

Tags: latex, org-mode, pdflatex, beamer

I'm using org-mode to generate beamer presentations. I have

```
(setq org-beamer-frame-default-options "allowframebreaks")
```

so my exported latex is like this:

```
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks,label=sec-1-1-1]{Framebreak test}
First List

\begin{itemize}
\item TEST
\item TEST
\item test
\item test
\item test
\item test
\item test
\item test
\item test
\end{itemize}

Second List

\begin{itemize}
\item TEST
\item TEST
\item test
\item test
\item test
\item test
\item test
\item test
\item test
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

However when I compile this with `pdflatex`, the framebreak does not work. (It just generate one slide for this page, remaining stuff truncated).

But if I manually remove `label=sec-1-1-1` so I only have `\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Framebreak test}`, `framebreak` works well. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIRC, this is related to bug #265 in Beamer itself. Until solved, you should try:

```
(setq org-beamer-frame-default-options "allowframebreaks,label=")
```

Answer (score 3):

Okay. It seems it is fixed in the newer version of org-mode - search for `Provide an automatic label for the frame` in the [source code](http://orgmode.org/w/?p=org-mode.git;a=blob_plain;f=lisp/ox-beamer.el;hb=HEAD). Apparently it hasn't been yet fixed in Org mode version 8.2.10. I guess I have to use the developmental version for now.

EDITED: with `Org mode 8.3beta`, if a heading has `:BEAMER_OPT: allowframebreaks` property, then `ox-beamer` will not generate the automatic label.